# UDP allocating a new socket for each new connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, udp

Here is my setup: On my home network a server is running on port `SERVER_PORT`. A port forwarding rule has been added to the router such that all incoming connections to `SERVER_PORT` will reach the server's machine. Somewhere else on the internet there exists a client who tries to send a UDP packet to the server and receive a packet back.

The server will receive the connection on `SERVER_PORT` but will send a packet back from a socket bound to a different (random) port.

The idea is emulating a listener socket just like the one used for TCP, and for each new connection allocating a new socket.

I have tested my program with clients that are connected to my home network, and outside the home network (cellular). The program didn't work either way.

The program does work though if I send a packet back using the server's original socket (the one that is bound to `SERVER_PORT`).

I am assuming this has something to do with my router's NAT table but I can't quite figure out the details.

My question is how can a packet be sent back from a different socket, other than the one that had been used for previous packets, and would I have had the same issue if the server was directly connected to the internet?

I wrote a small java program to demonstrate the issue:

Here is the server's code:

```
    //create both sockets and a buffer
    DatagramSocket serverSocket1 = new DatagramSocket(SERVER_PORT);
    DatagramSocket serverSocket2 = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

    //receive a packet from serverSocket1
    DatagramPacket packet1 = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    serverSocket1.receive(packet1);
    System.out.println("received packet from: address = " + packet1.getAddress() + ", port = "+ packet1.getPort());

    //send a packet from serverSocket2
    DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, packet1.getAddress(), packet1.getPort());
    serverSocket2.send(packet2);
    System.out.println("sent packet back");
```

Here is the client's code: (note: `SERVER_ADDRESS` is set to my public ip)

```
    //create a socket for the client and a buffer
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

    //send packet1
    DatagramPacket clientPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 0, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName(Server.SERVER_ADDRESS), Server.SERVER_PORT);
    clientSocket.send(clientPacket1);
    System.out.println("sent packet");

    //receive packet2
    DatagramPacket clientPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    clientSocket.receive(clientPacket2);
    System.out.println("received packet from: address = " + clientPacket2.getAddress() + ", port = "+ clientPacket2.getPort());
```

After running first the server and the the client I get the following output:

server:

```
received packet from: address = /107.107.56.147, port = 29098
sent packet back
```

client:

```
sent packet
```

Comment: As I understand it, UDP doesn't do a handover to a different port the way TCP does. You just use the original port (the server port), and the server has to manage the connections from multiple clients all on its own.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. But for some reason, I cannot send packets back from sockets other than the original server's socket, that's the issue.

Comment: I believe that you're supposed to send UDP using the original server port. I don't know what port serverSocket2 was initialized to, but I think it should look like a clone of serverSocket1. Of course, I haven't programmed using UDP for a hound's age.

Comment: That's interesting, why should it look like a clone of serverSocket1? Since UDP is a connectionless protocol it shouldn't matter where the packets are arriving from.

Comment: The client application needs to have some way of determining which packets come from where.

Comment: So as I see it that's what happens: serverSocket1 is publicly known. The client sends a packet to serverSocket1, by doing so, the server now knows of clientSocket and it can send a packet back to it from either serverSocket1 or serverSocket2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216892/discussion-between-roy-varon-and-nomadmaker).

Comment: UDP is a _connectionless_ protocol, and there is no such thing as a UDP connection.